# Adding StandardScaler() of values as new column to DataFrame returns partly NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nan

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df['total_price'].describe()
```

returns

```
count    24895.000000
mean       216.377369
std        161.246931
min          0.000000
25%        109.900000
50%        174.000000
75%        273.000000
max       1355.900000
Name: total_price, dtype: float64
```

When I apply `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` to it:

```
x = df[['total_price']]
standard_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x_scaled = standard_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df['new_col'] = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

<y new column with the standardized values contains some `NaN`s:

```
df[['total_price', 'new_col']].head()

    total_price new_col
0   241.95      0.158596
1   241.95      0.158596
2   241.95      0.158596
3   81.95      -0.833691
4   81.95      -0.833691

df[['total_price', 'new_col']].tail()

        total_price new_col
28167   264.0       NaN
28168   264.0       NaN
28176   94.0        NaN
28177   166.0       NaN
28178   166.0       NaN
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Your original column had `24895` entries, and your new DF has indices going all the way to `28178`, so my first guess that some sort of join or concatenation may have resulted in an index mismatch between the old and new DFs. Were there any intermediate steps not shown, like a train-test split?

Comment: it's part of a larger df and I removed rows before. But this was not inbetween the steps above

Comment: After reading your comment I did a `df = df.reset_index()` and 
the problem got resolved

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 4):

The indices in your dataframe have gaps:

```
28167 
28168  
28176  
28177  
28178
```

When you call `pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)` you are creating a new contiguous index and hence when assigining this as a column in the original dataframe, many lines will not have a match. You can resolve this by resetting the index in the original dataframe (`df.reset_index()`) or by updating `x` inplace (`x.update(x_scaled)`).